# Mysql получение содержимого поля в таблице.

Tags: php, mysql

Собственно, сам вопрос. Допустим, есть таблица users. Пусть там будут name, login, password. Нужно получить name пользователя, зная его login, или password. Или и то, и другое. **Подключение к бд есть**. Пробовал так:

```
$d_table=mysql_query("SELECT login FROM users WHERE login='$_SESSION["login"]'");
if (mysql_num_rows($d_table))
{
$res = mysql_result($d_table,0,"name");
echo $res;
}
```

С моим кодом вылетает ошибка: `name not found in MySQL result index [тут число] in [путь до файла где содержится этот код] on line [номер строчки с ошибкой]`

А сама строчка, в которой как бы вроде ошибка:

```
    $d_table=mysql_query("SELECT login FROM users WHERE login='$_SESSION["login"]'");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT login FROM
```

Ищите ошибку тут.
А вместо этого

```
if (mysql_num_rows($d_table))
{
    $res = mysql_result($d_table,0,"name");
    echo $res;
}
```

может лучше использовать

```
$res = mysql_fetch_assoc($d_table);
```

а после посмотреть результат через

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($res);
echo "</pre>";
```

чтобы точно знать что у вас выводится.